# Django sending wrong filename with UUID based download

Tags: django

Folks,

I'm having an issue that I can work around, but I'd prefer not to.

I just rewrote my gallery application, to use a UUID based database index for the download.  Eg.

```
url(r'^(?i)download/(?P<d_uuid>.+)/',
    frontend.views.new_download,
    name="downloads"),
```

So download/  will lookup the file by searching for the UUID, and then serve it out.  *But the filename that is saved by the browser is the UUID, and not the actual filename of the file.*

`def new_download(request, d_uuid=None):

```
download = index_data.objects.filter(uuid=d_uuid,
                                     ignore=False,
                                     delete_pending=False)[0]

print ("\tDownloading - %s, %s" % (download.fqpndirectory.lower(), download.name))
return serve(request,
             download.name,
             download.fqpndirectory.lower())
```

`

This was working properly before I switched to using the UUID search.  It appears that the browsers (firefox, Safari, etc), are grabbing the filename from the GET, and ignoring the filename that is being passed.

Now, I've tried using, this instead of serve.  The following code specifically adds the filename to the response, *but is being ignored*:

`    respond_as_attachment(request, download.fqpndirectory, download.name)

```
def respond_as_attachment(request, file_path, original_filename):
#   https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1710/
#   print ("original filename: ", original_filename)
    filename = os.path.join(file_path, original_filename) 
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(original_filename)
    if type is None:
        type = 'application/octet-stream'
    response['Content-Type'] = type
    print (response['Content-Type'])
    response['Content-Length'] = str(os.stat(filename).st_size)
    if encoding is not None:
        response['Content-Encoding'] = encoding
    filename_header='filename="%s"' % original_filename
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; ' + filename_header
    return response
```

`

Without any change in behavior.  I'm stumped...

The UUID switch has allowed me to simplify the code quite a bit.

Now I could write the incoming request, along this line:

[http://*servername*/download/*filename*?uuid=uuid](http://_servername_/download/_filename_?uuid=uuid)

And effectively ignore the filename portion.  That actually would be better for the log file (since the filename would show in the log instead of just the UUID).

Anyone have any suggestions?  And yes, I know serve is not recommended, but I need this to work in the development environment, as well as in the production (Apache w/mod_wsgi).

The current code is *NOT* yet posted at GitHub - https://github.com/bschollnick/QuickBBS.  The current snapshot up there is from before switching the UUID scheme.  I'm hoping to have the UUID scheme code up within the next couple of days, once I have finished switching it over, and have debugged issues like this.

```
    - Benjamin
```

Edit #3:

Solved - When testing, I didn't add the return for the new_download call.

```
print ("\tDownloading - %s, %s" % (download.fqpndirectory.lower(), download.name))
**respond_as_attachment**(request, configdata["locations"]["albums_path"] + os.sep + download.fqpndirectory, download.name)
return serve(request,
             download.name,
             download.fqpndirectory.lower())
```

Which meant the code was passing through respond_as_attachment, but it wasn't being sent to the server, which meant that I was receiving the download from the serve command.

Instead:

```
print ("\tDownloading - %s, %s" % (download.fqpndirectory.lower(), download.name))
**return** respond_as_attachment(request, configdata["locations"]["albums_path"] + os.sep + download.fqpndirectory, download.name)
```

Is working as expected.

I was staring at the code, and the answer was right in front of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See last edit.  Closing question.